# how to draw a bar plot using data from multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
  cost issue                  disposal issue
 1 "Not aware"                "Not aware"                      
 2 "Not aware"                "Not aware"                      
 3 "Not aware"                "Not aware"                      
 4 "Not aware"                "Not aware"                      
 5 ""                         ""                               
 6 ""                         ""                               
 7 "No"                       "No"                             
 8 "No"                       "No"                             
 9 "No"                       "No"                             
10 "No"                       "No"
```

I want to make a bar graph of these 2 variables which contain only "no" like this graph below

[image]

how to filter and graph using ggplot

Answer (score 0):

You can count number of "No" values in each column of the dataframe, get data in long format and plot. If `df` is the name of the dataframe -

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = ~sum(. == 'No'))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col() + guides(fill = "none")
```